# Google Apps marketplace: Chrome Webstore item id is not a valid id

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I am in the midst of the migration to the new Google Apps marketplace. All went so far fine. If I access the new Developer Dashboard in the Chrome Web store I can see my app listed. Under "more info" I can see an item ID. I thought so far this is the Chrome Webstore ID, which is required for all next steps. For example if I copy this now in the old Google Apps marke place "Enable OAuth2.0 upgrade" field we get Chrome Webstore item id is not a valid id.

So I wonder if this is the correct Chrome Webstore ID? Or whether I somehow did something wrong in publishing the app? How can I find the correct ID if I am already listed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The item ID shown under "More Info" is the correct ID. Have you tried again recently? It may have taken a moment for things to propagate through various systems.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. It still does not work, but the reason might be that I have to fill out first the "Google Apps Marketplace Listing Review Request". But that is not so obvious either and just a guess.

Comment: Is your Chrome Web Store listing published yet? It may need to be published and public before you can set it's ID in that dialog.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It is like catch 22. We try to publish the project on the Chrome webstore and get: "Unable to communicate with the API Console to verify the api_console_project_id field. Please try saving your changes again." On the old market place we can still not save the webstore ID. It is such a complicated process. :-(

Comment: I've seen the "Unable to communicate with the API Console" error before, and it was usually transient.

Comment: I'm seeing the same error since a few days. Do I just have to wait?